# getch() returns wrong characters

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, curses, getch

I'm experiencing problems with the `getch()` function of the `curses` library.
Suppose we have the following program:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    while 1:
        c = stdscr.getch()
        stdscr.addstr(chr(c) + ": " + str(c) + "\n")
curses.wrapper(main)
```

Let's run this, and enter the following characters: `a`, `<backspace>`, `œ`

Then the output is:

```
a: 97
ć: 263
Å: 197
```

As you see, the `a` character is taken correctly.
However, the  others are not. I just want to get the backspace `'\b'` and the unicode character `œ`, but we get something else.

Why does `getch()` behave this way, and how can I get the desired behaviour?

**EDIT:**

Let me emphasize that's it's not an issue with printing the characters, but with reading the characters. Namely, running `stdscr.addstr('œ')` indeed prints `œ`.

Comment: Which version of Python ?

Comment: The version is python 3.3

Comment: Looks like a bad interaction between encodings - what are your locale-specific variables set to, and are you doing any locale-specific setup in your Python code?

Comment: I don't do any encoding setup. Running `locale.getpreferredencoding()`
gives `'UTF-8'`.

Comment: Did you follow the note at http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html ?

Comment: Calling `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` at the start doesn't change the output.

Comment: Edited the question to emphasize the issue is with reading the chars, not with writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.3 the [`window.get_wch`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#curses.window.get_wch) function was added. It handles all of those characters correctly.

If you read the documentation for [`window.getch`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch), you'll notice that it doesn't claim to support non-ASCII printable characters. It just documents that it can handle non-ASCII key presses such as function keys or keypad keys.

**EDIT:**

When using `window.get_wch`, characters (e.g. `'a'`, `'ă'`, `'好'`, `'\n'`, or `'\t'`) are returned as strings. Function keys are returned as integers (e.g. `265` or `274`). Here is a new example to run. Try playing with the different keys you want to recognize to see how their values are returned. The format of the data printed is: `[repr]: [type]`.

```
def main(stdscr):
    while 1:
        c = stdscr.get_wch()
        stdscr.addstr("%s: %s\n" % (repr(c), type(c)))
```

Here is what I get when I type in `a`, `œ`, `<enter>`, `<backspace>`, and `<F1>`:

```
'a': <class 'str'>
'œ': <class 'str'>
'\n': <class 'str'>
'\x7f': <class 'str'>
265: <class 'int'>
```

If an integer is returned, you can find out the name of the key pressed via [`curses.keyname`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#curses.keyname):

```
>>> curses.keyname(265)
b'KEY_F(1)'
```

Comment: This indeed works for the `œ`, but the `<backspace>` (and `<delete>`, `<F1>`, `<F2>`,... etc) characters are still treated wrongly.

Comment: I added information to the answer about return values.

Comment: For me your script returns `'\n': <class 'str'>`,
`330: <class 'int'>` and
`265: <class 'int'>` when typing `<enter>`, `<delete>` and `<F1>`. So the `<delete>` is still treated wrongly, while it works apparently for you.

Comment: You got ``330`` when typing ``<delete>``. ``curses.keyname(330)`` returns ``'KEY_DC'``.

Comment: Backspace/Delete work differently on different computers. I'm running Mac OS X, where my "Backspace" (says "Delete" on it) returns ``'\x7f'`` -- the ASCII value for *Delete*. Your "Delete" key returned ``330``, which corresponds to the key name ``'KEY_DC'``. The ``KEY_DC`` constant [refers to the *delete character*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#constants). What do you get when you press ``<backspace>``?

Comment: It also depends on the terminal settings. [``curses.erasechar``](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#curses.erasechar) can be helpful here. ``erasechar`` returns ``b'\x7f'`` for me.

Comment: Yes, indeed `curses.keyname` returns the right names for `<delete>` and `<backspace>`. However, I expect (and need) to get `b'\x7f'` in the first place when pressing delete, instead of getting some other number. Similarly when pressing backspace, I need to have the `'\b'` character.

Comment: For me `curses.erasechar()` returns `b'\x7f'` as well.

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry that earlier I made a typo when I said that I pressed "delete" and got ``'\x7f'``. I should have said 'backspace'. Second of all, the ``<delete>`` key does not and should not return ``'\x7f'``. ``'\x7f'`` is an ASCII character, not a key name. The delete key doesn't correspond to an ASCII character, so you *shouldn't* expect it to. You *should* expect it to return ``curses.KEY_DC``. Third of all, the way to handle backspace is not to expect ``'\b'`` (or ``'\x08'``), but to expect whatever is returned by ``curses.erasechar()``. I hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: If you *must* have ``'\b'``, then yes, you'll need to handle that case manually. On some computers and terminals, ``'\b'`` may be returned by ``<backspace>``, that's why it's good to check ``curses.erasechar()``. The ``<delete>`` key probably shouldn't be considered ``'\x7f'`` (see [Wikipedia on the delete *character*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character) -- not *key*), but you can handle it that way if you need to.